# Exception from within a finally block

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, finally

Consider the following code where LockDevice() could possibly fail and throw an exception on ist own. What happens in C# if an exception is raised from within a finally block?

```
UnlockDevice();

try
{
  DoSomethingWithDevice();
}
finally
{
  LockDevice(); // can fail with an exception
}
```

Comment: Another good question is "what happens if a thread abort exception is raised after UnlockDevice unlocks the device but before the try-protected region is entered?"  The answer: the device stays unlocked. This looks like rather unsafe code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly the same thing that would happen if it wasn't in a finally block - an exception could propagate from that point. If you need to, you can try/catch from within the finally:

```
try
{
    DoSomethingWithDevice();
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        LockDevice();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```